Unable to Resolve com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0 Dependency Conflict in Android Project
I'm encountering difficulties resolving a dependency conflict related to com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0 in my Android project. Despite specifying the dependency in my app-level build.gradle file, I'm receiving a "Could not find" error during the build process.
Background:
I'm developing an Android application that requires integration with the com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0 dependency. However, despite specifying the dependency in my app-level build.gradle file, the build process fails to locate it. Additionally, occurrences of this dependency are detected within the project files.
Problem Description:
The primary issue is the inability to locate the com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0 dependency during the build process. The error message indicates that the dependency is required by the project, but it cannot be found. Furthermore, occurrences of this dependency are detected within the project files, indicating that it is referenced but not successfully resolved.
Current Implementation:
Here's the relevant section of my app-level build.gradle file where I specify the dependency:
implementation 'com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0'


Question:
How can I effectively resolve the "Could not find" error related to the com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0 dependency in my Android project?
Are there any additional steps or configurations required to ensure that the dependency is successfully resolved during the build process?
What are the possible reasons for the build process failing to locate the specified dependency, and how can I troubleshoot this issue effectively?
